# Saving and retrieving state of checkbox fields from database

Tags: java, database, recommendation-engine

Our application is web-based.  Our tools of trade are: Java, JDK1.6, Apache Tomcat v6.0.10, PostgreSQL v8.2.3.

We've a page/screen in the application that has got approx. 20 - 30 checkboxes, which just only denotes yes/no state of the fields.

My question here is, just before I settle down myself on my own design/architecture, I wanted to bounce my implementation with the community and get opinion/advice on how others are looking at/handling this type of design considerations.

**My solution/design:** Creating a table (USERPREFERENCE) with 3 columns: EMPLOYEEID, FIELDID, STATE.  Define/designate each checkbox field by a Unique ID/constant (1, 2, 3, ..., 30).  Hence, there would be 20 - 30 entries for each user in this table.  Is this normal or is there any different/better way of handling this effectively at the database-level?  Also, how do I map the state of 20 - 30 fields (stored row-wise) from database to a JavaBean object automatically, so that it becomes ease in handling back-and-forth at Java level?

USERPREFERENCE table looks like:

```
EMPLOYEEID | FIELDID | STATE
100        |   1     | true
100        |   2     | true
100        |   3     | false
...        |  ...    |  ...
```

Any advice/design alternatives are welcome and appreciated.

**NOTE:** We would also be developing another 4 page/screen with the same functionality having 20 - 30 checkbox fields in each screen.

**UPDATE:** Please take this into account: The fields are not fixed, new fields may get added in future.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are of a fixed length and you have a value for each field for most of your entities (`EMPLOYEEID`) I would opt for separate `boolean` columns for each field. It's more efficient from two points of view:

- storage: you don't have to store a `(EMPLOYEEID, FIELDID)` key for each value (and PostgreSQL is smart about storing booleans)
- ease of use: it's easy to query and map the values to your model

Comment: The fields are *not* fixed, new fields may get added in future.  Taking this into account, what would you advice?

Comment: @Gnanam:
How often will they change? Daily, monthly, yearly?
How difficult is it to maintain the model in case of changes? A couple of minutes, hours, days?

Except for the case when you need your application's users to be able to add/remove fields dinamically, I would not bother with an over-normalized structure like this. The changes in the model and db are usually trivial (add new bean properties and ORM mappings) compared to changes in the user interface and data validation.

Comment: Roughly, I could say that fields may change yearly or so.  Even if it happens in yearly, I'm trying to avoid/atleast reduce the amount of time required to maintain the model and DB, though I understand that it not difficult.  Atleast Java coding should be minimized to the maximum possible.